# jQuery submitHandler: function not displaying data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I am using jQuery to input data to a php file and return the results via json. However, the json is appearing in firebug, but the variable 'messageOutput' is not displaying results on the form. If I replace 'messageOutput' with 'msg.box' then it prints fine.

If I enter more than 1 item on my form, then it errors with: 'object object'.

Can someone point out where my error is as I have been struggling with this for ages. If you need to see any further code, please ask. many thanks.

jQuery code:

```
submitHandler: function()   {
                if ($("#BA_boxform").valid() === true)  { 
                var data = $("#BA_boxform").serialize();
                $.post('/domain/admin/requests/boxes/boxesadd.php', data, function(msg) {

               var messageOutput = '';
                for (var i = 0; i<msg.length; i++){
                    messageOutput += msg[i].box+'  ';     
                }
        $("#BA_addbox").html("You have entered box: " + "<b>" + messageOutput + "</b><br /> You may now close this window.");
                $("#BA_boxform").get(0).reset();
                }, 'json');

         } else

         { 
           return; 
         }
        },
        success:    function(msg)   {
                //$("#BA_addbox").html("You have entered a box");
                //$("#BA_boxform").get(0).reset();
        }
```

boxesadd.php

```
<?php

     $dept = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['customerdept']);
     $company = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['BA_customer']);
     $address = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['customeraddress']);
     $service = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['BA_service']);
     $box = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['BA_box']);
     $destroydate = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['BA_destdate']);
     $authorised = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['BA_authorised']);
     $submit = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['submit']);
     $boxerrortext = 'You must enter a box for intake';

     $array = split('[,]', $_POST['BA_box']);

     if (isset($_POST['submit']))   {
      foreach ($array as $box) {
      if (empty($box)) {
       $error = array('boxerrortext'=>$boxerrortext);

     $output = json_encode($error);

     echo $output;


     }
    else
     {

     $form=array('dept'=>$dept,
                 'company'=>$company,
                 'address'=>$address,
                 'service'=>$service,
                 'box'=>$box,
                 'destroydate'=>$destroydate,
                 'authorised'=>$authorised,
                 'submit'=>$submit);
     $result=json_encode($form);

     echo $result;
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its hard to debug it without knowing what the the request response looks like. Are you sure that the server returns an array? I'm not familiar with php, so i am not to helpful there, looking quickly it seems that the php 'array' is really more akin to a js object literal then a js array. I.e. it looks like it is a bunch of key/value pairs.

in which case, you should use the for/in loop instead of the for/each

```
for ( var key in msg ) 
    messageOutput += msg[key] // => concats dept, company, address, etc
```

if you are really expecting an array of those objects (where you have a bunch of objects with the prop 'box') then you are doing it correctly in the javascript but you may not be sending the right object back from the server.

can you pop open the dev panel/firebug and show us what is being returned from the server?
try adding:

```
 console.log($.isArray(msg))
```

and seeing if it returns true or not. One way of ensuring what is returned is an array is to use, what i call a splat utility:

```
function splat(obj){
  return $.isArray(obj) ? obj : [ obj ];
}
```

this makes sure you are always dealing with an array, albeit sometimes an array of one time

Comment: Where would I put the console.log statement? I have tried like this but nothing is showing console: var messageOutput = '';
                for (var i = 0; i<msg.length; i++){
    
                    messageOutput += msg[i].box+'  '; 
     console.log($.isArray(msg));    
                }

Comment: put it outside the loop, right above it. if it is in the loop and it isn't firing that suggests to me that msg isn't an array